# Show that the error of quadratic interpolation $\xi$ is given by $\xi\le|E|+\frac{5}{4}\epsilon$

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, numerical-calculus, error-propagation

Show that the error of quadratic interpolation $\xi$ in equidistant points, the values of which are obtained by rounding and the error is lesser or equal to $\epsilon$, is given by:

$$\xi\le|E|+\frac{5}{4}\epsilon$$

I got as far as
$$\prod^n_{i=0} (x-x_i)\frac{f^5}{5!} \le |E|+\frac{5}{4}\epsilon$$

I don't know what |E| is. Help?

Answer (score 2):

You know that $|\hat y_i-f(x_i)|\le ϵ$, where $\hat y_i$ are the rounded function values.

Now
\begin{alignat}{1}
\left|f(x)-\sum_{i=0}^n\hat y_iL_i(x)\right|
&\le \left|f(x)-\sum_{i=0}^n  f(x_i)L_i(x)\right|&+\sum_{i=0}^n |\hat y_i-f(x_i)|·|L_i(x)|\\
&\le |E(x)|&+ϵ\sum_{i=0}^n|L_i(x)|
\end{alignat}
where $L_i(x)$ is the Lagrange interpolation kernel for position $x_i$.
The graph of the sum in the last term for $x_i=i$, $i=0,1,2=n$ is

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. What is E(x)? Where is the 5/4?

Comment: $E(x)$ is the error at point $x$ of the exact interpolation, the constant is the local maximum $1.25$ in the plot.